# Entity Framework: Attaching an entity of type FixedAssets failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a Web API program that uses EF. Right now, I am having some CRUD functions in my controller, which are working for Creating a new object, Deleting an object and reading an object. The problem comes when I try to Update an object which exists in my database, receiving the error from the title. I already tried some solutions from the people who also had this problem and asked a question here, but nothing worked for now.

Here is my code:

The method from my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateAsset")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateAsset(HttpRequestMessage request, FixedAssetsView assets)
    {
        return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(k => ModelState[k].Errors)
                          .Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
            }
            else if (!service.isInDatabase(assets.ID))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Couldn't find the assets you want to update");
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(k => ModelState[k].Errors)
                      .Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
            }
            else if (service.isInDatabaseAfterInventoryNo(assets.inventoryNo) && service.getAssetIdAfterInventoryNumber(assets.inventoryNo) != assets.ID)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid object", "An assets with the same inventory number already exists");
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(k => ModelState[k].Errors)
                      .Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                if (service.wasUpdated(assets))
                    response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
                else
                    response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }

            return response;
        });
    }
```

The methods I use from my service:

```
    public bool isInDatabase(int ID)
    {
        return assetsRepo.FindBy(asset => asset.ID == ID).Any();
    }

    public bool isInDatabaseAfterInventoryNo(int inventoryNo)
    {
        return assetsRepo.FindBy(asset => asset.inventoryNo == inventoryNo).Any();
    }

    public int getAssetIdAfterInventoryNumber(int inventoryNo)
    {
        return assetsRepo.FindBy(asset => asset.inventoryNo == inventoryNo).First().ID;
    }

    public bool wasUpdated(FixedAssetsView assets)
    {
        FixedAssets singleAsset = Mapper.Map<FixedAssetsView, FixedAssets>(assets);
        assetsRepo.Edit(singleAsset);
        unitOfWork.Commit();
        return true;
    }
```

The methods I use from my repository:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry<T>(entity);
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified; /*HERE IS WHERE RECEIVE THE EXCEPTION*/
    }
```

Here is my DBContext method:

```
    private InventoryManagementContext dataContext;

    protected InventoryManagementContext DbContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DbFactory.Init()); }
    }
```

My DbFactory method:

```
    protected IDbFactory DbFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

My IDbFactory interface:

```
public interface IDbFactory : IDisposable
{
    InventoryManagementContext Init();
}
```

My InventoryManagementContext:

```
public class InventoryManagementContext : DbContext
{
    // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
    // 
    // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
    // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
    // For more information refer to the documentation:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

    public InventoryManagementContext() : base("name=InventoryManagementContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<InventoryManagementContext>(null);
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<InventoryManagement.Models.InventoryObjects> InventoryObjects { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<InventoryManagement.Models.FixedAssets> FixedAssets { get; set; }

    public virtual void Commit()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FixedAssetsConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new InventoryObjectsConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you setup a PK in FixedAssets? What is its value? How are you managing the lifecycle of your repo/UoW?

Comment: My FixedAssets has as the PK the ID you can find in my code. I don't really understand the lifecycle question :/

Comment: "lifecycle" means are you creating the context for each request or creating it once and using it for entire lifetime of application?

Comment: I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. For the ones who will have it in the future, I updated my FindBy function

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate).AsNoTracking();
}
```

Notice the "AsNoTracking()" addition.